# What is the meaning of assert(0 == pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock));

Tags: c, pthreads, assert

I was debugging a piece of code and encountered a statement:

```
assert(0 == pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock));
```

Can anyone explain me what is the interpretation of this statement.

My understanding is that , the assert will terminate the program if pthread_mutex_destroy() method doesn't return a zero.

Can anyone tell me if my understanding is correct

Comment: Note that this is not generally a safe construct - at least if using the standard `<assert.h>` facility where `assert` is a preprocessor macro. If compiled for "release" (with `NDEBUG` defined), the entire line will disappear, and the mutex won't get destroyed. Better to do: `rval = pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock); assert(rval == 0);`

Answer (score 0):

If successful, `pthread_mutex_destroy()` will return zero, otherwise, an error number will be returned to indicate the error.

This will assert if mutex_destroy() is not a success.

---

`pthread_mutex_destroy()` will fail for this reason:

- [EINVAL]: The value specified by mutex is invalid.
- [EBUSY] : Mutex is locked.

Comment: But anyway, if the destroy fails, the assert fails and will abort the program with a message"assert failed". The assert intends to catch errors that should not happen and for which no recovery has been programmed.